# Can't goto root of website anymore

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm making a new website and had lots of help overhere before with the htaccess to make it all work. Nevertheless I can't reach the root of the website www.placewomen.com anymore...it's looking for /c/c when I aspect the index.html of the root....My htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^placewomen.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.placewomen.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+new/index\.php\?var=([^\s&]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$1 -f [OR]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$1 -d [OR]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$1 -l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /c/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /new/index.php?var=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/placeholder.jpg -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/placeholder.jpg [L]
```

Comment: Does it work without "www."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^placewomen\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.placewomen.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+new/index\.php\?var=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/placeholder.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/placeholder.jpg [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$1 -l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /c/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /new/index.php?var=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: OEPS... but now I http://www.placewomen.com/b/123/435/ + http://www.placewomen.com/s/123/435/ doesn't work anymore...it should show the placeholder.jpg image...??

Comment: Ok try reverting only that rule to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/placeholder.jpg -f` as you had before.

Comment: ehh...I have it now back with no working root. Could you please paste the full modified htaccess because I don't understand it...

Comment: have a beer and CHEERS!